# Does Debian have a x86-64 Distro?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, debian

Looks like Debian has AMD64 and IA64 versions, but does not have a x86-64 version, is this correct?

Or AMD64 includes x86-64?

Comment: AMD64 and x86-64 refer to the same thing.

Comment: also, this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 9):

AMD64 and x86-64 (and sometimes a64) refer to the same thing.
Debian has had an official build for that architecture since Etch (v4.0).